# how to prevent tomcat from hacker?

Tags: security, tomcat

Today I recognized that my tomcat 6.0 has been deployed a strange webapp called jFoler 0.9.
After looking around, I realize that this webapp can upload, download, delete file on the server and computer system also. It also can do some cmd control, so I think it's very dangerous to my company if this happens again.

So how can I protect my server against the hacker?

Comment: check www.cgisecurity.com/appservers/tomcat/6265.pdf and http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/projects/THREDDS/tech/tds4.2/reference/TomcatSecurity.html second one is more batter

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Server admin related questions belong on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3):

1 install firewall

2 place tomcat box behind firewall

3 configure firewall to only allow access to port 80 on the tomcat machine to external devices and non admin internal devices.